# Installing Archive::ZIp Perl package with cpan on centos7 fails with "not in gzip format"

Tags: perl, cpan

I have a CentOS 7 VM.  I installed "cpan-CPAN" from yum.  I ran "cpan" and let it configure itself.  I ran it with sudo, although I realized later I didn't necessarily have to do that, if I later selected the "sudo" installation mode.

After it finished configuring, I entered "install Archive::Zip".  It gave me this:

```
cpan[1]> install Archive::Zip
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://cpan.mmgdesigns.com.ar/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz'

gzip: /root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz: not in gzip format
............................................................................DONE
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://cpan.mmgdesigns.com.ar/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'

gzip: /root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz: not in gzip format
Warning: Your /root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz does not contain a Line-Count header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
Warning: Your /root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz does not contain a Last-Updated header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
Could not split line["                  </td>\cM"]
Could not split line["                </tr>\cM"]
Could not split line["              </tbody>\cM"]
Could not split line["            </table>\cM"]
Giving up parsing your /root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz, too many errorsReading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz'

gzip: /root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz: not in gzip format
............................................................................DONE
Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'

gzip: /root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz: not in gzip format
Warning: Your /root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz does not contain a Line-Count header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
Warning: Your /root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz does not contain a Last-Updated header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
Could not split line["                  </td>\cM"]
Could not split line["                </tr>\cM"]
Could not split line["              </tbody>\cM"]
Could not split line["            </table>\cM"]
Giving up parsing your /root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz, too many errorsTerminal does not support GetHistory.
Lockfile removed.
```

What should I do at this point?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of downloading `02packages.details.txt.gz`, the CPAN mirror (http://cpan.mmgdesigns.com.ar) returned HTML output to you, possibly a 404 error message.

Perhaps that CPAN mirror is not serving CPAN files anymore, or perhaps you are behind a proxy and your proxy did not want to serve a file from ... Argentina, is it?

Comment: The site comes up for me. If you don't get another mirror working and you're curious, use another tool (like `wget` or `curl`) to download that file and see what you get.

Comment: I don't know what was really happening, but I just reran cpan to let it config itself, and it ended up with a different list of repos, and then I was able to install it.